# Trying to allow access for another user to picture folder through windows powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$sharepath = "C:\foldername"
$Acl = Get-ACL $SharePath
$AccessRule= New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("everyone","full","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","none","Allow")
$Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $SharePath $Acl
```

This is the code I found when searching for answers however it did not work for me.

The error message I am getting:

```
At line:1 char:28
+$sharepath = "C:\Pictures" $Acl = Get-Acl $Sharepath $AccessRule= New ...
+                           ~~~~~
Unexpected token '$Ac1' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          :ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: This is working fine here. Your error message is about Ac1 (1, not L). I doubt you are sharing the script with us which doesn't work for you?

Comment: It looks like you're pasting these commands in as a single line, and that's why it's complaining that it doesn't know what to do with "$Acl". Just run the commands individually, or put semicolons after each line, and you should get a different result.

Comment: @MartinBrandl - Yes, I think jbsmith has it correct.  It looks like they're assuming it can all be on one line for some reason.  Your edit, while helpful, is actually _the answer_  :)

Comment: @gravity You are probably right :-)

Comment: Thank you! yes I was putting it all on one line